# Obtain primary key of newly inserted row in PostgreSQL trigger

Tags: postgresql

In PostgreSQL I'm trying to make a database trigger on an `INSERT` that passes the primary key of the new row as the payload of a channel notification using `NOTIFY`

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around the correct usage age of the `NEW` variable in this context. No matter what I try seems to generate a syntax error.

Below is a simplified example of my use case.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION table_event_notify_function()
RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN
    NOTIFY table_event_notify, NEW.id;
    return NULL;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER table_events_insert_trigger AFTER INSERT ON table_events EXECUTE PROCEDURE table_event_notify_function();


psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "NEW"
```

Comment: `CREATE TRIGGER table_events_insert_trigger AFTER INSERT ON table_events FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE table_event_notify_function()`

Comment: And in your function, it could be `RETURN NEW` instead of `RETURN NULL` but it's not an issue as the function call is `AFTER INSERT`

Comment: @Edouard: the `create trigger` is not the problem. The `notify` with dynamic parameters is.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name actually your solution only worked after I introduced `FOR EACH ROW`. The channel notification was being called but the payload was empty without specifying it. So I was doing two things wrong. Thank you both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The payload parameter for NOTIFY must be a constant. To provide a dynamic parameter, you need to use `pg_notify()`

```
perform pg_notifiy('table_event_notify', new.id::txt);
```